# Copying image and link onto another website

Tags: html

I have 2 websites, i have an image with a link on both websites i want to make it so when one of those images and links is changed the other on the other website changes also, is this possible in anyways?

Comment: Your question needs further clarification, but from what i understand you can serve your images on both sites from an api endpoint or web service.

Comment: What kind of website do you have Thomas? Is the backends or frontend in your control (PHP, Python, etc. involved?) or do you have a website or blog engine you use, e.g. Wix, Wordpress? The answer depends on your setup. Some options are well written by @Marc at the answers section.

Answer (score 3):

Your best options would be:

a) Use ajax to pull in the content on both sites, for example with jQuery:

```
<div id="linked-image"></div>
<script>
$('#linked-image').load('https://www.yoursite.com/file-with-your-html.html');
</script>
```

b) Use an iframe on both sites, both of which use a common `src` attribute:

```
<iframe src="https://www.yoursite.com/file-with-your-html.html"></iframe>
```

c) Use an API call to retrieve the image src and link href from a common endpoint source, and then load to both sites dynamically